# How to make simple MySQL Order by Alpha sets (a-z,a-z,a-z...)

Tags: mysql, sorting, alphanumeric

I've written a kids word game and now I'm trying to optimize performance. Game picks keywords from database with a special sort a I want to do it better.

Given a MySQL keyword field sorted alphanumerically:

```
keyword     sorting position

apple              1
apricot            2
avocado            3
banana             4
broccoli           5
carrot             6
cherry             7
coconut            8
grape              9
```

Is it possible (in one simple MySQL query) to sort them in successive alphanumeric groups so each group have keywords which first letter is different from others in group? 
Result expected is like this:

```
keywords      group alpha sorting position

apple               1
banana              2
carrot              3
grape               4
apricot             1
broccoli            2
cherry              3
avocado             1
coconut             2
```

I have achieved this by programing iteration. I would like to  know if this can be done in one simple MySQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables:

```
SELECT keyword
FROM (
  SELECT keyword,
         @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn,
         @grp_rn := IF (@grp = LEFT(keyword, 1), @grp_rn + 1,
                       IF (@grp := LEFT(keyword, 1), 1, 1)) AS grp_rn
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @grp_rn := 0, @grp := '') AS var
  ORDER BY keyword) AS t
ORDER BY grp_rn, rn
```

`@rn` simply enumerates tables records by ascending `keyword` order. `@grp_rn` enumerates records that belong to the same `LEFT(keyword, 1)` (i.e. first letter of `keyword`) slice.

To understand better how sort using `ORDER BY grp_rn, rn` works, you can have a look at what the subquery returns:

```
keyword,  rn, grp_rn
====================
apple,    1,  1
apricot,  2,  2
avocado,  3,  3
banana,   4,  1
broccoli, 5,  2
carrot,   6,  1
cherry,   7,  2
coconut,  8,  3
grape,    9,  1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c58c/3)

Comment: Excellent! it works perfect.
I am still figuring out how it works. So few lines but it is a crash course on MySQL variables. I guess some of the magic happens using `IF` statement to declare and test variable at the same time. Do you use `CROSS JOIN` to initialize them?
Pure magic, advanced stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @AlbertSoares Yes, `CROSS JOIN` is the typical way to initialize variables. Check the result set returned by the subquery in order to understand how variables work.